# Erro no momento de assinar uma Hash em SHA256 usando Certificado Digital

Tags: .net, vb.net, sha-256

Esta retornando erro de *Algoritico inválido Especificado*, quando vai ser assinado, como prosseguir?

```
 Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Me.txtCNPJEmpresa.Text + Me.txtCNPJSoftwareHouse.Text)
 Dim csp As RSACryptoServiceProvider = DirectCast(Certificado.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)

 Dim sha As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
 Dim hash As Byte() = New Byte() {}
 hash = sha.ComputeHash(data)

 Dim encrypted As Byte() = csp.SignHash(hash, "SHA256")
```

Comment: Qual linha retornou erro? Qual a exception retornada (não apenas a mensagem)? Qual a versão do .Net utilizada?

Comment: Na linha da assinatura, quando vai adicionar a chave na variável encrypted, VS12

Comment: Tem certeza que é assim mesmo que se assina? SHA-256 é um algoritmo de hash, não de assinatura digital, mas ele é *usado* em outros algoritmos de assinatura, tal como o HMAC-SHA256 (embora não creia ser o seu caso). Você não estaria procurando o `RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter`? Veja [esse exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hk8wx38z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). É muito comum - quando se quer assinar um dado arbitrário - primeiro fazer um hash desse dado e então assinar o hash, isso é usado em diversos protocolos, só não sei se se aplica ao seu caso.

Comment: Então, quando uso o padrão SHA1, mudando apenas as classes, da certo, mas quando uso SHA256 da esse erro, pois todas as pesquisas que fiz a galera usa esse modelo que citei ai encima, sem falar que alem de eu ter que gerar em SHA256 eu tenho que assinar usando meu certificado digital.

Comment: @FelipeWalleg A cerca do certificado digital, seria a nova versão de certificados? Existem certificados de cadeia v2 e v3. Se não me engano, esse mês ou mês passado foram alterados a cadeia de certificados digitais. Verifique se o certificado consta G2,G5...G7, pois a versão G7(V3) estão com alguns problemas dando erro na validação do mesmo. Não sei se envolve o mesmo problema com a sua assinatura, mas segue um dos problemas que tive por aqui a cerca de assinaturas e foram resolvidas, Caso seja, eu posto como resposta a resolução do problema.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias causas possíveis; porém a mais comum é quando o certificado emitido não suporta o algoritmo de assinatura desejado.

Para verificar, abra o certificado e selecione `Detalhes`. O seguinte item deve estar presente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso necessário, re-emita o certificado com suporte ao algoritmo de assinatura `SHA256`.

Comment: Ono, está assim o meu, igual a imagem que postou, mesmo assim retorna o erro de algoritimo inválido Especificado

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim.

Dim csp As SHA256 = DirectCast(Certificado.PrivateKey, SHA256CryptoServiceProvider)

Não consigo testar agora, mais acho que está dando conflito na aplicação 
RSA x SHA256.

Comment: E o que me sugere?

Comment: bom cara, tente usar está classe, X509 certificates, eu uso em xmls para assinar  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Olha esse exemplo simples, rodando direto o o SHA256 em um texto, debuga os metodos para adicionar o certificado, no caso, o id do certificado certo? para usar como palavra chave.

```
Private Function Encriptar(ByVal TextoEncriptar As String) As String
    Dim TextoEncriptado As String
    Dim TextoBytes() As Byte

    'Saber os Bytes do texto a encriptar
    TextoBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(TextoEncriptar)

    'Nova Instancia SHA256
    Dim HashSha As New SHA256Managed

    'Calcular hash do texto em bytes
    TextoBytes = HashSha.ComputeHash(TextoBytes)

    'Converter o array de bytes 
   TextoEncriptado  = Convert.ToBase64String(TextoBytes)


    Return TextoEncriptado 
  End Function
```

> http://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/topic/18165-criptografia/

Comment: Então, mas se vc reparar nesse método não tem a assinatura, isso eu tenho aqui funcionando, mas o problema é quando adiciona o SignHash ou SignData, ambos dão esse erro de algorítimo inválido